# Heroku deployment: How can I point my app to app/client/build?

Tags: node.js, heroku, server, client, mern

How can I point my app to app/client/build?

I get the error: "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/server/build/index.html'" when deploying my app to Heroku. I added my package.json, server.js and my app structure.

App ->

->Client

-build

-public

-src

-components

-App.js

-index.js

->Server

-db

-routes

-server.js

-package.json

-Procfile

- etc....

It needs to point to app/client/build/index.html.

I don't know where heroku is getting the app/server part in app/server/build/index.html from, I know it is getting build/index.html part from the below code found in server.js:

'''

```
// server static in prod env
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
//   Set static folder
  app.use(express.static('build'));

  app.get('*', (req,res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'))
  });
}
```

'''
Full server.js file
'''

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const cors = require("cors");
require("dotenv").config({ path: "config.env" });
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(require("./routes/record"));
// get driver connection
const dbo = require("./db/conn");

// server static in prod env
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
//   Set static folder
  app.use(express.static('build'));

  app.get('*', (req,res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'))
  });
}

app.listen(port, () => {
  // perform a database connection when server starts
  dbo.connectToServer(function (err) {
    if (err) console.error(err);

  });
  console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`);
});
```

'''

I suspect 'app/server/' part might be coming from the way npm builds the app but I just a suspicion.
package.json:

'''

```
    {
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "cd server && node server.js",
    "heroku-post-build": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client",
    "server": "cd server && node server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^7.0.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^14.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "mongodb": "^4.3.1"
  }
}
```

'''

Please let me know if I should add other files that may help troubleshoot this. This community is amazing btw! So glad for everything I'm learning on this platform.

Answer (score 0):

I added client/build to the static and resolve statements and the app now points to the build folder on heroku:

'''

```
app.use(express.static('client/build'));

  app.get('*', (req,res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/build', 'index.html'))
  });
```

'''